# why oci_bind_by_name not working if inside oracle function

Tags: php, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-call-interface

Sorry for my bad english. I think it would be easier if I just put my codes here. So here is what I have tried:

//this is working

```
$sql = "select ID, NAME, BDATE from EMPLOYEES where BDATE >= DATE '2020-01-01'";
```

//but when I tried to do this, it fails:

```
$sql = "select ID, NAME, BDATE from EMPLOYEES where BDATE >= DATE :bdate"; //this is 
$compiled = oci_parse($conn, $sql);
oci_bind_by_name($compiled, ":bdate", "2020-01-01");
```

above will raise this error:

> "code":936,"message":"ORA-00936: missing expression"

I have tried something else like:

//fail

```
$sql = "select ID, NAME, BDATE from EMPLOYEES where BDATE >= TO_DATE(:bdate, 'YYYY-MM-DD')"; 
oci_bind_by_name($conn, ':bdate', '2020-01-01');
```

above will raise this error:

> "code":1847,"message":"ORA-01847: day of month must be between 1 and
>   last day of month"

//always fail when I put inside function like DATE, TO_DATE, UPPER, etc

```
$sql = "select ID, NAME, BDATE, STATUS from EMPLOYEES where upper(STATUS) = upper(:status)";
```

//event in In clause will also fail

```
$sql = "select ID, NAME, BDATE, STATUS from EMPLOYEES where upper(STATUS) in (:status1, :status2)"; 
oci_bind_by_name($compiled, ":status1", "SINGLE");
oci_bind_by_name($compiled, ":status2", "MARRIED");
```

Could please anyone tell me how to fix this?
I have followed many tutorial from the documentation, and also from another stackoverflow answers. But nothing works.

Or is it maybe there is something I missed to set on my web server? or on my database server?

Fyi, I am using PHP7.2, OCI8, Oracle 11g.

thank you very much.

Comment: Not sure, but try setting the value in a variables - `$date = "2020-01-01";` and then put the variable in the bind `oci_bind_by_name($compiled, ":bdate", $date);`

Comment: thank you. i have done that. I event put it directly without variable into oci_bind_by_name. like this: oci_bind_by_name($conn, ':bdate', '2020-01-01');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me on php 7.4,Oci8/Oracle 19c database.(I never worked on php just googled here and there)

```
    $sql = "SELECT ename FROM emp WHERE hiredate > TO_DATE(:hdate,'YYYY-MM-DD')";
    $stid = oci_parse($conn, $sql);
    $hdate = "1980-01-01";
     oci_bind_by_name($stid,':hdate', $hdate);
   // oci_bind_by_name($stid,":hdate", $hdate);  //this line also works i.e double quotes
```

Edit:- IN clause also works for me.This is what I learned you cannot pass literal values in OCI_BIND i,e first assign literal to a variable

```
$sql = "SELECT ename FROM emp WHERE job IN (:job1,:job2)";
$stid = oci_parse($conn, $sql);
$job1 ='CLERK';
$job2 = 'SALESMAN';
oci_bind_by_name($stid,':job1', $job1);
oci_bind_by_name($stid,':job2',$job2);
oci_execute($stid);
```

Check these [link1](https://doc.bccnsoft.com/docs/php-docs-7-en/function.oci-bind-by-name.html) [link2](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.oci-bind-by-name.php) for examples that works with Oracle Database

Comment: ah I didnt know that we cannot pass literal values in oci_bind. let me try it. thanks

Comment: WOW!!! I have never thought that it is the problem. We just can not pass literal values, must use a variable. It work now after I put them in a variable. What a weird behaviour this PHP :) thank you so much Sam. I pick your answer accepted for that note.

Comment: update: after doing more research. ive figured out that the key is that we must pass the value by refference variable. as it is the definition of the oci_bind_by_name function.

Answer (score 1):

`DATE '2020-01-01'` is the ANSI [date literal](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements003.htm#BABGIGCJ) syntax. It's a mechanism to type raw dates in your code and it doesn't make sense with variables or placeholders, thus the error.

As already mentioned, you can use the [`TO_DATE()` function](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions183.htm) as alternative.

Comment: thank you for mentioning that it is a date literal syntax. I didnt know it. I have been using it a lot because it works :). i will try again with TO_DATE function with a variable as Sam below said that we should not use a literal value, must use a variable. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
where BDATE >= TO_DATE(:bdate, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

but only if you provided date value in **exactly** the same format you specified: `YYYY-MM-DD`. Error you got:

> ORA-01847: day of month must be between 1 and last day of month

means that you provided an invalid string, e.g. `2020-05-38` - there are no 38 days in any month, and Oracle expects number between 1 and 31 (as there are 31 days in May).

---

Check default date format using

```
SQL> select * From nls_session_parameters where parameter = 'NLS_DATE_FORMAT';

PARAMETER            VALUE
-------------------- --------------------
NLS_DATE_FORMAT      DD.MM.RR

SQL>
```

which means that you'd - in my database - pass value as `18.05.20` for today's date.

Comment: Thank you but actually I passed '2020-01-01' for the value. But somehow it raise that error.

Comment: Sorry, I misinterpreted the error message; fixed. As of value you pass: that just shouldn't happen; every month has day "01" so ... Maybe it has something to do with environment you work with (PHP7.2, OCI8, Oracle 11g). See default NLS settings and date format in the database. Then try to use date in that format. I edited my message and added query you might use.

Comment: my NLS_DATE_FORMAT=DD-MON-RR

I have tried this:
            oci_bind_by_date($conn, ":end_date", '01-JAN-2020');
it raises this error: "code":936,"message":"ORA-00936: missing expression"

I suspect that i have something missing on the server setup.

Comment: Maybe ... I don't know PHP so I can't help much. Googling around mentions something like `date("d-M-Y H:i:s")` so - maybe `date ("01-01-20")` would help? If not, I'm afraid I don't have other ideas.